# Drawable tinting for api <21

Tags: android

Is it possible to make drawable tinting work for api < 21?

```
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar"
    android:tint="@color/primary" />
```

Works just fine but only for devices with API21. Any workaround for lower api devices or AppCompat support? Can't find anything.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Use the `AppCompatImageView` like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_appcompat_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image"
        android:tint="#636363"
    />
```

Make sure you have the latest `appcompat-v7` in your app's `build.gradle`.

Example: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'` in your app's `build.gradle`.

Comment: From `AppCompatImageView` docs: `This will automatically be used when you use ImageView in your layouts. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html So, using the normal `ImageView` in the layout should work just fine.

Comment: As @NimrodDayan mentioned above, this shouldn't be necessary. I am getting reports of android:tint not working on a Samsung A5 and Moto G, however (using appcompat-v7:23.4.0), so it's possible ImageViews aren't being replaced properly on some devices.

Comment: @StephenKidson, I'm using the same version of appcompat and also bumped into the same issue on an unknown brand device. Did you manage to solve this? I wonder if there's bug reported about this...

Comment: @NimrodDayan worked around it by making a separate drawable XML for the color I was tinting to - not ideal but pretty much the only way to ensure the issue was resolved without getting ahold of each affected device.

Comment: This did not work on emulator Android 4.0 using appcompat-v7:25.1.0.

Comment: AppCompatImageView cannot be used inside a Widget. Use setColorFilter on the ImageView.

Answer (score 46):

You can achieve that using source code.
Previously tinting was not supported by `DrawableCompat`.
Starting from support library 22.1 you can do that, but you need do it in this way:

```
Drawable normalDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawable_to_tint);
Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(normalDrawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight));
```

Comment: If you need to support tinting on < 21 APIs, then you probably want to use `ContextCompat.getColor()` instead of `getResources().getColor()`.

Answer (score 22):

Couldn't you simply use an ImageView to display your Drawable? `android:tint` works fine on older API levels.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar"
    android:tint="@color/primary"
    />
```

Comment: I am using ImageView - to display icon in it. Those icons are part of elements in my navigation drawer. And selected item in navigation drawer has different color, so I created each icon tinted and also selector for each icon. And I am using that selector for my icon.

Selector:
`<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_home_tinted" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_home" />
</selector>`

Comment: @Orochi Take a look at my answer as it come directly from Google's blogs. It mainly only works on Android 5.0+ but may work on some widgets for devices running pre-Android 5.0.

Comment: @Orochi You are going to have to make custom views to "emulate" the same effect.

Comment: @Orochi: Ah, sorry, misunderstood the context.

Comment: So, should I just color the icon myself and put it in my drawable folder?

Comment: You could use an image view, make the icon as white as possible, and make it any color you want with iv.setColorFilter(yourColor,  Mode.Multiply); Make sure you import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode

Comment: Same problem here. Sadly the tint with selector does not work with api < 21

Answer (score 17):

A similar question has been asked before here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26533340/950427

Android Drawable Tinting is supported in Android 5.0+ (API 21+) only. (It does say "`At the moment this is limited to coloring the action bar and some widgets.`").

> ### Theming
>
> ...
>
> **When you set these attributes, AppCompat automatically propagates
> their values to the framework attributes on API 21+.** This
> automatically colors the status bar and Overview (Recents) task entry.
>
> **On older platforms, AppCompat emulates the color theming where
> possible. At the moment this is limited to coloring the action bar and
> some widgets.**

And

> ### Widget tinting
>
> **When running on devices with Android 5.0, all of the
> widgets are tinted using the color theme attributes we just talked
> about.** There are two main features which allow this on Lollipop:
> drawable tinting, and referencing theme attributes (of the form
> ?attr/foo) in drawables.
>
> AppCompat provides similar behaviour on earlier versions of Android
> for a subset of UI widgets:
>
> Everything provided by AppCompat’s toolbar (action modes, etc)
> EditText Spinner CheckBox RadioButton Switch (use the new
> android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat) CheckedTextView You don’t need
> to do anything special to make these work, just use these controls in
> your layouts as usual and AppCompat will do the rest (with some
> caveats; see the FAQ below).

Sources:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is from the official documentation.

Comment: Answer is outdated. `ImageView` also now supports `android:tint` via AppCompat, as in @Jonik's answer.

Comment: @VickyChijwani Submit an edit. And you mean `AppCompatImageView`, not `ImageView`.

Answer (score 13):

Now AppCompatImageView,AppCompatButton will replace the ImageView,Button to support tint on devices with lower API. Check link for more details
[AppCompatImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html),[AppCompatButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html)

Answer (score 6):

For tinting images you could use `imageView.setColorFilter(int color)`. This works from API 8 and worked for tinting my black image to a color I wanted.
This can replace `setImageTintList()` but just using `android:tint` should also work.

Answer (score 5):

Use this NameSpace
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

and after you can replace every android:tint with app:tint. This fix the 
issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little late but here's how to do it.

```
val textInput = EditText(context)

val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.your_drawable)
drawable?.let {
    myDrawable -> DrawableCompat.setTint(myDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color))
    textInput.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, myDrawable, null)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do as you want, and should work on all Android versions of the support library:

Kotlin:

```kotlin
    @JvmStatic
    fun getTintedDrawable(inputDrawable: Drawable, @ColorInt color: Int): Drawable {
        val wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(inputDrawable.mutate())
        DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, color)
        DrawableCompat.setTintMode(wrapDrawable, Mode.SRC_IN)
        return wrapDrawable
    }
```

Java:

```java
    public static Drawable getTintedDrawable(Drawable inputDrawable, @ColorInt int color) {
        Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(inputDrawable.mutate());
        DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, color);
        DrawableCompat.setTintMode(wrapDrawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        return wrapDrawable;
    }
```

Comment: I like this answer. `mutate()` and `wrap` is required for SDK < 21. For SDK >=21, the functions will just return the `inputDrawable` so there is no cost to use these functions. Besides, after wrapped, actually `setTint` and `setTintMode` can be directly called from `wrapDrawable` without using `DrawableCompat`'s static method.

Comment: @ChesterFung In case the SDK>=21, what should it look like (please check before answering) ?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone want create new drawable (tin1,tint2..) try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:src="@drawable/your_image"
  android:tint="@color/tint_color">
   </bitmap>
```