# Changing color of material icons?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I downloaded a number of material icons from here:

https://material.io/icons/

I'm confused as to how I change the color of these icons as drawables. I have one `Button` with an icon in the `drawableLeft` property, and then a number of `ImageButton` with icons set, like so:

```
<Button
    android:text="Hey"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_arrow_upward_black_24dp"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_downward_black_24dp"
    android:background="@null" />
```

How do I change the color of the icons for each?

Additionally, if the icons I downloaded are black, how can I change the color of the icons to a color with transparency?

Answer (score 43):

You do realize **All the Material Icons** at https://material.io/icons/ are now available in **Android studio**, **No need** to even download them. Just right click on **drawables > New > Vector Asset**

You will get a dialog like

[image: this]

After click on the little **Android icon**, select your image and save. This will the create an  **xml drawable** Which can be opened and edited to your liking

Here is how it will look like

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:alpha="0.8" <!--set the transparency from here -->
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000" <!-- Use this for setting your color -->
        android:pathData="M9.4,16.6L4.8,12l4.6,-4.6L8,6l-6,6 6,6 1.4,-1.4zM14.6,16.6l4.6,-4.6 -4.6,-4.6L16,6l6,6 -6,6 -1.4,-1.4z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: I want to create more accounts so that I can upvote this answer more times. Google needs to update their material icons website to reflect this information!

Comment: Vector drawables used to have poor support on earlier versions of Android (requiring the use of multiple pngs). But the latest versions of AppCompat will allow you to use vector drawables like this even when supporting older versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678947/how-to-properly-use-backwards-compatible-vector-drawable-with-the-latest-android

Answer (score 10):

Add this to your ImageButton in your xml layout file

```
android:tint="@color/black"
android:tintMode="@color/black"
```

Comment: What versions of Android is this compatible with? What about `Button`?

Comment: Also, if I try setting a transparent color this way, they show up as mostly black (I'm assuming because the downloaded icon is black, and the tint is just applying the transparent color over the black, instead of replacing the black).

Comment: For me `tintMode` was not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If your icons are vectors, you can edit the xml file and change the `android:fillColor` attribute. If the icons are bitmaps, you can add `android:tint` attribute to the ImageButton.

Answer (score 1):

All of the appcompat widgets support the `android:tint="@color/somecolorresource"` attribute. If your activity/fragment extends `AppCompatActivity/Fragment` this will work for any `ImageView/TextView/ImageButton/...`.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37261384/3662251

Comment: If I try setting a transparent color this way, they show up as mostly black (I'm assuming because the downloaded icon is black, and the tint is just applying the transparent color over the black, instead of replacing the black).

Comment: The tint is applied by using a color filter. This is most likely causing the actual color to "leak" when you use a transparent color.

Comment: You can use a regular color and use the `android:alpha="0.5"` attribute on the view to make it transparent.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/icon_slayer/) is great for editing icons, you can generate icons with transparent background too. hope this helps.