# Error inflating ImageView / ImageButton with ColorStateList tint value

Tags: android, imageview, android-appcompat, android-4.4-kitkat, tint

Using an `ImageView` / `ImageButton` (`AppCompatImageView` / `AppCompatImageButton`) in conjunction with a style attribute of `android:tint` which makes use of a `ColorStateList` resource works fine on >= API 21, but throws an `InflateException` on API < 21.

Firstly, I don't even know whether the `AppCompatImageView / (Button)` tinting supports `ColourStateList` xml resources as an `android:tint` value, I can't seem to find a definitive answer to this.  Suggestions I can find on S/O suggest implementing a `TintableImageView` etc, but these answers are quite dated, and it seems from the source of the appcompat implementations this should be a feature.

To clarify this is definitely the issue.  Removing the `android:tint` attribute or setting it to a single colour resource works.

Also to clarify, I'm aware this is achievable programmatically.  I'm trying to get it backwards compatible in xml.

### Minimal example

#### activity_foo.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_caret_up"
                style="@style/IconButton.Primary"

/>
```

#### styles.xml

```
<style name="IconButton.Primary">
    <item name="android:tint">@color/link_button_color</item>
</style>
```

#### link_button_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:color="@color/btnLinkPressedTextColor"
      android:state_selected="true" />
  <item android:color="@color/btnLinkPressedTextColor"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
  <item android:color="@color/btnLinkTextColor" />

</selector>
```

Comment: can you try replacing hexcode directly instead of getting it from @color

Comment: Does this occur when using ImageViews? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155463/drawable-tinting-for-api-21

Comment: It occurs when using ImageView, ImageButton (which get replaced at compilation with their appcompat variants) or explicitly specifying their appcompat variants, as in the example I've provided.

Answer (score 4):

In my case i replaced `android:tint` with `app:tint` and added to root element `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`. It fixed crashing issue on API level < 21.

And color state selector **/res/color/color_selector.xml** looks like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#151515"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#151515"/>
    <item android:color="#424242"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like AppCompat drawable tinting only works for action bar and "some widgets" on < API 21, but works for all drawables on API 21+.

> When you set these attributes, AppCompat automatically propagates their values to the framework attributes on API 21+. This automatically colors the status bar and Overview (Recents) task entry.
>
> On older platforms, AppCompat emulates the color theming where possible. At the moment this is limited to coloring the action bar and some widgets.

Source: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

The answer here also has more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29155611/608312

Comment: Tinting itself works, and I can see it present in the source.  I'm specifically talking about ColourStateList tinting, which again, seems to be present in the source, but I can't find a definition anywhere of whether this is officially supported

Answer (score 0):

item name="android:tint" is wrong.

fix the 'android:tint' to 'tint'

```
<style name="IconButton.Primary">
    <item name="tint">@color/link_button_color</item>
</style>
```