# How change icons color on API < 21?

Tags: android, performance, drawable, android-4.4-kitkat

Because API 19 (KitKat) is still very popular, it's a good choice to support this release. However, it does not support many features, such as backgroundTint and ImageTint. This puts me in various compatibility issues and design choices.

I have several icons to load on a screen and I'm currently using setImageTintList to make the app dynamic.

[image]

The "faces" and "bucks" should change color according to the element in a recyclerView. What is the best way to support this function on systems with API <21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what APIs you exactly mean by saying "backgroundTint and ImageTint", but there's a compatibility [`ViewCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html) class which will backport some functionality up to API 4.

Amongst them are:

- [`setBackgroundTintList(View, ColorStateList)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.view.View,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList))
- [`setBackgroundTintMode(View, ColorStateList)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setBackgroundTintMode(android.view.View,%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode))

If by saying "ImageTint" you meant [`android:tint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:tint) or [`setImageTintList()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)), then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29155463/1083957) answers your question.