# Android imageview tint

Tags: android

While setting tint for an ImageView in xml, I am getting a warning that shows:-

***Must use app:tint instead of android:tint***

Why should I use app:tint?

Comment: Docs still mention `android:tint` instead of `app:tint`. Seems they should be updated. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#attr_android:tint

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because there were some issues where `android:tint` wasn't working for version < 21. `app:tint` works under version 21. Here is a similar problem. [Drawable tinting for api <21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155463/drawable-tinting-for-api-21)

Answer (score 17):

In `AppCompatImageView` it's fine, you could use `android:tint`.

Comment: This is the actual answer !!!

Answer (score 8):

ImageViewTintDetector lint check was added in [androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.2.0-alpha02)
[Add Lint rule to check android:tint usage on ImageView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/1f6aefd576d8df0b47abba8197a8b470fa3e0c3e)

Actually I have not found explanation why should developer replace android:tint with app:tint.
My project minSdkVersion is 22.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a bug of Android Studio to me, as it doesn't take into account your `minSdkVersion` and also `app:tint` is not supported well in designer preview. It confuse and slow  me repeatedly as I don't remember stuff like this when going back to android development.

Hopefully one day they will improve it to be really useful and account also your `minSdkVersion` but for now it look like its best to ignore that by going to preferences editor inspection and disable `app:tint attribute should be used on` completely.

Edit:
For versions > 24 . Right now I bumped back into this, after reading somewhere that I should use app:tint for some possible compatibility issues I did that to my whole codebase. Then I realised that actually I have new issue after this change when tested on older devices so I reverted back to normal android:tint again.. issues where related to theme change that I do in my apps so somehow appcompat tint doesn't work the same as regular at last when I test in simulators form api 24 and my two more recent android devices, appcompat make actual issues regular works in my testing perfect so I hope I am not wrong with this.

Comment: Which android versions? bdw, you can add tools:ignore="UseAppTint" to disable the warning.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's a bug. I have an XML with 3 ImageViews that are the exact same (they're copies of eachother), and I get that error in one of them only. Weirdly enough, clicking on `Fix` converts that line from `android:tint="..."` to `card_view:tint="..."`.

Only solution so far was to add `tools:ignore="UseAppTint"` to silence this warning.