# Error: Unknown issue id "UseAppTint" [LintError]

Tags: android, lint

Running lint on an Android project (using Bitrise) results in `Unknown issue id "UseAppTint" [LintError]`

**module_build_shared.gradle:**

```
    lintOptions {
        quiet false
        abortOnError true
        ignoreWarnings true
        disable 'UseAppTint' // Using `android:tint` on an ImageView is only a problem when API < 21 (our current minSDK is higher)
    }
```

This is an example of a lint error I'm trying to disable:

````
ProjectName/modulename/src/main/res/layout/my_layout.xml:60: Error: Must use app:tint instead of android:tint [UseAppTint]
android:tint="?attr/colorOnSurface"```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some [issues with tint on api < 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155463/drawable-tinting-for-api-21).

You could change that `ImageView` to `AppCompatImageView` and use `app:tint` in the xml and you'll get rid of that warning.