# Android: Drawable <android:tint> alternative API < 21

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Having to support night and day mode for API < 21 is a bit exhausting.
Android API >= 21 has allowed the use of android:tint like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_status"
    android:tint="@color/white" />
```

The previous made changing the tint color of the icon depending on the night mode very easy. However, it is not supported on API < 21. Which means I need two versions of every single item in my app (with different screen sizes). Is there any easier way??

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532045/tinting-checkbox-on-pre-v21?answertab=votes#tab-top) suggested creating a new style. But the events `colorControlNormal` and `colorControlActivated` are not what I'm looking for.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155463/drawable-tinting-for-api-21?answertab=votes#tab-top) suggested using `AppCompatImageView` but I made my layouts with `AppCompatButton` and specified the `drawableTop`

Comment: use `DrawableCompat#setTint(Drawable drawable, int tint)`

Comment: @pskink In this case I will have to check each time for the mode in order to tint with the suitable color

Comment: mode? what mode? you mean `setTintMode` or what?

Comment: @pskink No, I have two modes for the app, Day & Night. Each has different colors for the icons

Comment: so yes, you need an `if` for those two modes