# UI Compatibility Issues Between Different API Versions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-resources, android-4.4-kitkat

I am working on an app which utilizes a Navigation Drawer (which I generated from Android Studio's Activity template), which uses `fragments` internally. The Navigation Drawer is nested into my `MainActivity`. I have also included a menu into the toolbar which has two more options; Filter & Settings (Settings generated from AS template too). I ran into issues when I tested the app between APIs 19 and 24.

My LoginActivity uses the `drawableLeft` attribute along with a `drawableTint` (which I'm aware only works for API23 and higher). How can I get the drawableLeft icon to display in white on older versions?
[image: LoginActivity]

My second, more major issue, concerns the `Toolbar` and its compatibility. In API 24 (simulated using Nexus 5X), the `Toolbar` is well-aligned underneath the Status Bar, whereas in API 19, the `Toolbar` goes underneath the Status Bar which also has a mismatched colour. Now, I am aware that the Toolbar is a new addition to Material Design hence being supported from API 23+ (I think), but what would be the correct approach in fixing this?

[image: MainActivity]

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.michael.whatsupldn.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/london_skyline_dark"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:contentDescription="@string/london_skyline"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

P.S. If any code is needed to help the analysis, just ask away.

***EDIT***

I have also encountered the same `Toolbar` problem within my FilterActivity...
[image: FiltersActivity]

***UPDATE***

After applying `fitsSystemWindows` to `AppBarLayout` and `CoordinatorLayout`, this is the following result, which has not fixed my issue. It has actually made the case worse as it destabilised the output in API 24.

[image: MainActivity after EDIT]

Comment: For 1st issue: are you setting color of drawable like @color/white or #ffffff?

Comment: @UsmanRana I'm setting it this way: android:drawableTint="#FAFAFA"

Comment: Are u using vector Assets for this drawable?

Comment: @ArnabKundu Yes, I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue #1 was fixed thanks to *Arnab Kuntu*.

Issue #2 I managed to thankfully find a solution for myself when playing around with the themes within `styles`. My `AppTheme` had the following declaration nested within `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`, making the `Status bar` transparent, which makes the simulator think there is no foundation to support the `Action Bar / Toolbar` resting underneath.

Answer (score 2):

I think your vector code is like this.....

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:pathData="M12,17c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 
    0.9,2 2,2zM18,8h-1L17,6c0,-2.76 -2.24,-5 -5,-5S7,3.24 7,6v2L6,8c-1.1,0 
    -2,0.9 -2,2v10c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h12c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L20,10c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 
    -2,-2zM8.9,6c0,-1.71 1.39,-3.1 3.1,-3.1s3.1,1.39 
     3.1,3.1v2L8.9,8L8.9,6zM18,20L6,20L6,10h12v10z"/>
 </vector>
```

change this line of code

```
     android:fillColor="@color/colorWhite"
```

to.....

```
     android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
```

If I am not wrong this is the solution for you.
[image]

Comment: Yes, that worked - thank you so much, great answer! Have you by any change looked at the second issue I've mentioned?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532045/tinting-checkbox-on-pre-v21

Comment: You can go through this link this is related with buttonTint.But for checkbox I have used. Not sure it will work for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the drawableLeft icon to display in white on older versions?

You can make use of [`DrawableCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html):

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.some_drawable);
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable.mutate(), getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
```

<sup>[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30928051/1083957)</sup>

> What would be the correct approach in fixing this (toolbar allignment)?

Apply `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to both `Toolbar` and its parents.

Comment: Ok, I have included in the Toolbar now, but what would its parent be? I have included my XML code for the app_bar...

Comment: Apply `fitsSystemWindows` to `AppBarLayout` and `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: Please take a look at my post, I've updated it with the output. It has not worked for me.

Comment: @Programmer101, apply styles as specified in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28041425/1083957) answer.

Comment: I've taken a look at the answer, however, that doesn't seem to help me as it's focused towards transparency, whereas what I'm looking for is help with `ActionBar` / `toolbar` layout compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can set color programmatically and it would work for you:

```
// 0=left, 1=top , 2=right , 3=bottom
    editText.getCompoundDrawables[0].mutate().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```